# C3P0 won't start configured in Hibernate properties with Spring?

Tags: hibernate, spring, maven, c3p0

I'm using Hibernate 3.3.1GA and Spring 3.0.2 (and Maven from eclipse). I added c3p0-0.9.1 jar to classpath, and first tried this approach (configuring c3p0 within datasource bean):

```
<bean id="dataSource2" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass" value="${ora.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${ora.url}" />
    <property name="user" value="${ora.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${ora.password}" />

    <property name="minPoolSize" value="${minPoolSize}" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="${maxPoolSize}" />
    <property name="maxIdleTime" value="${maxIdleTime}" />
    <property name="maxStatements" value="${maxStatements}" />
    <property name="acquireIncrement" value="${acquireIncrement}" />
</bean>
```

This seems to **work**, as I can see c3p0 log in the eclipse console.
However, when I tried configuring it within hibernate sessionFactory properties, like this:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory2" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean" name="sessionFactory2">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource2" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.query.substitutions">true 1, false 0</prop>

            <!-- C3P0 properties (hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period)  -->
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">1</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">600</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">1</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</prop>

        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="mappingResources">
        <list>
                     ...
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

this **doesn't work**, c3p0 just won't start, no output, no error, nothing...
Actually, I don't find it so strange , because when I opened hibernate-core-3.3.1.GA jar from Maven repository, I couldn't find *org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider* class. I tried some other versions of hibernate (3.3.2, 3.6.0), and still same thing was happening (no C3P0ConnectionProvider class was in jar file). I treid removing *connection.providerclass* property, no difference.

I read a ton of related questions here and on other forums, and I can't really understand what's the problem. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303988/hibernate-3-3-and-c3p0) is basically my problem, but I didn't find it useful. Am I missing something in the properties configuration, did I name them wrong or something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using spring data source configuration (you refer `dataSource2` bean), I think, session factory bean just sets data source and Hibernate is ignoring it's own connection configuration.

If first approach works, why would you want the second one?

Comment: Why would I want the second one? Well, it's not that I want one of these in particular :) I'm just trying out different options, and trying to find what's the best for my needs. I read somewhere that first approach is maybe better, when spring-aop transaction management is enabled, which is my case. Maybe I should also consider configuring data source in JNDI (with tomcat)?

Comment: First approach always served me well.

Answer (score 1):

Worked for me though. I used something like this

```
<property name="hibernateProperties">
  <props>
    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
  </props>
</property>
<property name="hibernate.dialect">
        org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
   </property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">
        ${hibernate.connection.driver_class}
   </property>

    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">
        ${hibernate.connection.url}
   </property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">
        ${hibernate.connection.username}
   </property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">
        ${hibernate.connection.password}
   </property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">1</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">1</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">3</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">1000</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">2</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.numHelperThreads">3</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">60</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
```

-Raaghu.K

Comment: What are these properties, where did you put them (guess `sessionFactory` bean)? If you don't mind, edit your question to include more detailed overview of your xml config.